# How do I write this has_many_to_many dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I am trying to create a has many to many relationship between a `Goal` model. A goal can have dependent goals and a goal can have others goals that rely on it.

So far I have come up with the below, but it does not seem to be working.

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :goal_status
  belongs_to :goal_type

  has_many :users, through: :user_goals
  has_many :user_goals

  has_many :dependers, class_name: 'GoalDependency', foreign_key: :dependee_id
  has_many :dependees, class_name: 'GoalDependency', foreign_key: :depender_id
  has_many :dependencies, through: :dependees
  has_many :depending, through: :dependers

  validates_presence_of :goal_status_id, :goal_type_id
end


class GoalDependency < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dependee, class_name: 'Goal', foreign_key: 'dependee_id'
  belongs_to :depender, class_name: 'Goal', foreign_key: 'depender_id'
end
```

Schema

```
  create_table "goal_dependencies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "dependee_id"
    t.integer  "depender_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "goals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "goal_status_id"
    t.integer  "goal_type_id"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end
```

I am getting the error

```
Could not find the source association(s) "dependency" or :dependencies in model GoalDependency. Try 'has_many :dependencies, :through => :dependees, :source => <name>'. Is it one of dependee or depender?
```

I have tried putting in a couple of different values as the source, but nothing is working. I am not really familiar that much with using source.

I would guess this is possible in rails. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry,but i want say your `associations` set-up looks soo complex.The words `dependers`,`dependees`,`dependencies` and `depending`  are confusing and drives me crazy.

Comment: @Pavan I don't mind changing it - any suggestions welcome. I will try give it a bash to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking @Pavan's advice I changed the language around and managed to get it working that way. See the code below.

```
 class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :goal_status
  belongs_to :goal_type

  has_many :users, through: :user_goals
  has_many :user_goals

  has_many :parent_goals, class_name: 'GoalDependency', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :child_goals, class_name: 'GoalDependency', foreign_key: :child_id
  has_many :children, through: :child_goals
  has_many :parents, through: :parent_goals

  validates_presence_of :goal_status_id, :goal_type_id
end

class GoalDependency < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Goal', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  belongs_to :child, class_name: 'Goal', foreign_key: 'child_id'
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "goals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "goal_status_id"
    t.integer  "goal_type_id"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end

create_table "goal_dependencies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.integer  "child_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Comment: This looks much better :)

Comment: @Pavan Hmmm ... after further investigation the results that I am getting are not working. It keeps pulling it's self when I say `goal.parents` and `goal.children` doesn't work. No errors though.